# TouchDown events keep getting promoted to MouseLeftButton events

Tags: wpf, touch, windows-8.1

In a WPF application running on Windows 8, TouchDown events are always promoted to MouseLeftButton events. I don't know why, and want to avoid this.

Here's a complete sample code :

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="TestTouchAndMouse.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled="False">
    <Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas" Background="White" IsManipulationEnabled="False">
        <TextBox x:Name="TB" InkCanvas.Top="50" InkCanvas.Left="10" FontSize="20" />
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

C#

```
namespace TestTouchAndMouse
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyCanvas.MouseLeftButtonDown += MyCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown;
            MyCanvas.MouseRightButtonDown += MyCanvas_MouseRightButtonDown;
            MyCanvas.TouchDown += MyCanvas_TouchDown;
        }

         void MyCanvas_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
         {
             e.Handled = true;
             TB.Text = "MOUSE RIGHT !";
         }
         void MyCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
         {
             e.Handled = true;
             TB.Text = "MOUSE LEFT !";
         }
         void MyCanvas_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
         {
             e.Handled = true;
             TB.Text = "TOUCH !";
         }
     }
}
```

On Windows 7

- everything works fine.

On Windows 8

- MouseLeftButton or MouseRightButton events will show "Mouse left!" or "Mouse right!" as expected.
- **TouchDown events will show really quickly "Touch!" and then the text will change to "Mouse left!".**

Comment: Which mouse button is being triggered after a touch? Are you sure it's the left mouse button, or is it the right?

Comment: It's the LeftMouseButton that is triggered after a touch. I'll edit my question. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm. I've tested the code you've posted, and I don't get the problem you've described. If I press and hold for a second, I get a mouse down event due to the 'Press and Hold' emulating mouse right click events. You can disable that under the Pen and Touch settings in the control panel to rule that out. Another possibility is your touchscreen driver is emulating mouse down events. What make/model of screen are you using?

Comment: I have the same issue with windows 10, and funny is that i have 2 different touchscreens connected at the same time. One of them is working right and second have the touch/mouse problem. I try to install other drivers but windows does not allow my to install Dell drivers because drivers fom microsoft are newer.... have somebody some solution?

Comment: Sad that after all this time there's still no solution :-(